# Bad Request error when trying to refresh Django login access token

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

Trying to refresh the access token I receive from Django every few seconds, however I am getting the error message

`Request Method: POST Status Code: 400 Bad Request`

I am sending my refresh token to this endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/refresh/"

This is my urls.py:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView, TokenVerifyView)

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    # path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/', CustomTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('api/token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
    path('api/register', RegisterApi.as_view()),
]
```

This is how I am sending my refresh token:

```
let updateToken = async ()=> {
        try {
            let response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/refresh/',JSON.stringify(authTokens.refresh))
            //update state with token
            setAuthTokens(authTokens => ({
                ...response.data
            }))
            //update user state
            const decoded = jwt_decode(response.data.access)
            setUser(user => ({
                ...decoded
            }))
            //store tokens in localStorage
            //we stringify because we can only store strings in localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('authTokens',JSON.stringify(response.data))
            }
        catch(err) {
        //if fail, something is wrong with refresh token
            console.log(err.response)
        }
    }
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
data:
refresh: ['This field is required.']
[[Prototype]]: Object
headers:
content-length: "39"
content-type: "application/json"
[[Prototype]]: Object
request: XMLHttpRequest
onabort: ƒ handleAbort()
onerror: ƒ handleError()
onload: null
onloadend: ƒ onloadend()
onloadstart: null
onprogress: null
onreadystatechange: null
ontimeout: ƒ handleTimeout()
readyState: 4
response: "{\"refresh\":[\"This field is required.\"]}"
responseText: "{\"refresh\":[\"This field is required.\"]}"
responseType: ""
responseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/refresh/"
responseXML: null
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
timeout: 0
upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, onload: null, …}
withCredentials: false
[[Prototype]]: XMLHttpRequest
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

This is what i have in authTokens:

```
{refresh: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90e…9tIn0._aS9oDcj3Rfomodbs9qMEFmgEm4oEdOfSwGSJJKLWmg', access: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90e…20ifQ.K1YCXWoMWF7o61fGAuVm-QoehB3-jA2A_dLZ4o4uYa8'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/api/token/refresh/` returns only the `access` token.

When you `setAuthToken` using the entire response data, you are most likely getting rid of the `refresh` token.

Now the next time you make the request, `authTokens.refresh` is undefined and thus does not get sent to the backend. The backend rightfully complains that it's a 400: Bad Request. `refresh` is a required field.

Modify your frontend code to only update the `access` token. When the `refresh` token expires, you need to call `/api/token/` to login again.

Alternatively you can change the backend to rotate refresh tokens. This would send a new `refresh` token each time the `access` token is refreshed.
This is achieve by setting `ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS = True` in your settings.

If you want to make sure the old refresh token can no longer be used, you can blacklist them when rotated, by setting `BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION = True`